# Meteor Countdown

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am developing a task application where the user inputs a task with a certain duration. I want to display a counter that shows for each task how much time the user has left. I have added the flyandi:reactive-countdown from the atmospherejs which works if I follow their example but in my case things are different. I have the following helper which returns the counter each seconds.

```
Template.tasks.helpers({
    getCountdown: function() {
        return countdown.get();
    }
});
```

This is the counter variable which is **GLOBAL** otherwise it doesn't work.

```
var countdown = new ReactiveCountdown(30);
countdown.start(function() {
    // do something when this is completed
});
```

As you can see in this case it uses a pre-defined value which is 30, but I want to use a variable. The problem is that the variable that I use to calculate how much time the user has left for that task is defined inside another function which makes her not accessible on a global scope. If I create that variable as global it doesn't work as it loads before the helper that I use to update its value.

```
Template.tasks.events({
    'click #startTask':function(event){
        console.log(this.taskName);
        var duration=this.duration;
        var numb = duration.match(/\d/g);
        numb = numb.join("");
        console.log(numb);
    }
});
```

numb in this case is the time that the user has to finish the task but if I use something like new ReactiveCountdown(numb) this will display undefined as the script is run before the helper. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you share the variable via a collection and use template-level subscriptions to load and update the countdown?